# Event set component using a collada object in A-Frame (webvr)

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

I am trying to create a rotating animation on a collada object using the event set component plugin for A-frame, I have successfully been able to achieve this using a-box but would like animate the collada object instead. For some reason I cannot see the collada object and I don't know where I'm going wrong. Please see the code below for more info and any help would be highly appreciated , thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Model Test</title>
<script src="build.js"></script>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="component/event-proxy.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.x/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-layout-component@4.1.0/dist/aframe-layout-component.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity id="container" position="0 0 -2">
    <a-collada-model src="iPhone4.dae"
        animation__rotationX="property: rotation; dur: 10000;
                        easing: easeInSine; loop: true; to: 0 360 0;
                        startEvents: rotY; pauseEvents: animationPause;
                        resumeEvents: animationResume; restartEvents: animationRestart"
        animation__rotationY="property: rotation; dur: 10000;
                        easing: easeInSine; loop: true; to: 360 0 0;
                        startEvents: rotX; pauseEvents: animationPause;
                        resumeEvents: animationResume; restartEvents: animationRestart"

      position="0 1 -2">
    </a-collada-model>
    <a-mixin id="option"
             geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: .25;"
             material="color: red"
             event-proxy="listen: click; target: a-collada-model"
             ></a-mixin>
    <a-entity  position="-2.5 0 0">
      <a-entity mixin="option" event-proxy="emit: rotY" text="value: Rotation"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
    <a-entity  position="2.5 0 0">
      <a-entity mixin="option" event-proxy="emit: rotX" text="value: Rotation"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>

    <a-entity position="0 -1.5 0">
      <a-sphere mixin="option" event-proxy="emit: animationPause" text="value: Pause"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>


  <!-- Sky. -->
  <a-sky color="#0fbbff"></a-sky>

  <a-entity position="0 0 3">
    <a-camera><a-cursor color="#FFF"></a-cursor></a-camera>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, upgrade to 0.6.0. Im not sure how about the event and animation components, but afaik the model handling is better in 0.6.0.

Then try to use the collada loader as a component, instead of a primitive, like in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/collada-model.html):

```
<a-entity collada-model="src:iphone4.dae"></a-entity>
```

If You can't make the model to appear, You might want to switch the format to threejs json, or .glTF, by uploading Your iphone to clara.io, or using [khronos](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF)/[kupoman](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf) exporters, and then using Don McCurdy's [loaders](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders) .

---

Btw You don't seem to have issues with events, but with models, so the topic is kinda off :p